# Firebase python admin sdk isNewUser ()

Tags: python, django, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Hi i'm currently using firebase admin sdk on my django server to handle my app. I would like to check if user a user first time login on the server side.I would like to use firebase [isNewUser()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo.html#isNewUser()) on the django server but in the firebase admin sdk [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth) i don't see any information related to that.

My server side to get user from token(send from app):

```
from utils.firebase_utils import auth

class FirebaseAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        token = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']

    if not token: 
        return None 

    try:
        decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(token)
        uid = decoded_token['uid']
        user = auth.get_user(uid, app=None)
       # need to check if user first time log in too
    except Exception as e:
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No such user') 

    return (user, None) # authentication successful
```

How can i check if a user first time login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There indeed is no `isNewUser` method in the Admin SDK for Python.

A workaround is to compare the `creation_timestamp` and `last_sign_in_timestamp` properties of the [`UserMetadata object`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#usermetadata). If the two are close (within 1 second of each other), it is a new user. This is in fact how the documentation said to check for "newness" of a user record before the `isNewUser` method was introduced, which happened because there was a granularity difference in the two timestamps for a short while.

Comment: if it within 1 second so it's not much reliable because it depend on the network